# Mistake in Type Theory encyclopedia entry

Tags: logic, type-theory

There seems to be mistake in the [entry](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory/#2) for Type Theory in the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy:

> First-order logic considers only types of the form

> $i,…,i → i$    (type of function symbols), and
> $i,…,i → o$    (type of predicate, relation symbols)

with "the form" referring to $i → … → i$ and $i → … → i → o$.

Above, there stands:

> $(i→o) → o$    (type of predicates of predicates) corresponds to the type $((i))$

And still above:

> the type of quantifiers over individuals is $((i))$.

Thus $(i→o) → o$ ~ $((i))$ should be a type of FOL as well (note that $(i→o) → o$ ~ $((i))$ makes sense since quantifiers are higher-order relations). Any objections?

Comment: I voted to.close because I concur with what Rob Arthan wrote 6 years ago: there is a reading under which the contents of the SEP make sense, explained in the answer below. Beyond that, the question reduces to "wouldn't it be better if SEP phrased something as X instead of Y", which is out of scope, the same way "wouldn't it be better if Stewart's book used Newton notation instead of Leibniz notation" would be.

Answer (score 2):

It may be confusing that the article uses both Principia notation like $((i))$ and Church's notation $(i \rightarrow o) \rightarrow o$ and also uses the notation with commas whereby, for example,  $i, o \rightarrow o$ means $i \rightarrow o \rightarrow o$. . However,  $(i \rightarrow o) \rightarrow o$ does not have either of the forms $i, \ldots, i \rightarrow i$ (i.e., $i \rightarrow \ldots \rightarrow i \rightarrow i$) or $i, \ldots, i \rightarrow o$  (i.e., $i \rightarrow \ldots \rightarrow i \rightarrow o$) that belong to first-order logic. That is to say, the variable and constant symbols of first-order logic cannot have such a type.

Comment: This is what the article claims, yes. But then, according to the article, the type of quantifiers over individuals is not a type of FOL (assuming that the type is $(i→o)→o$ in Church's notation).

Comment: Yes: $\forall$ has type $(i \rightarrow o) \rightarrow o$ and you can't have variables of that type in FOL.

Comment: The claim is "First-order logic considers only types of the form...". The question is whether quantifiers over individuals are types of FOL, not what are the types of variables in FOL

Comment: FOL doesn't have types. From a higher-order perspective,  quantifiers in FOL have type $(i \rightarrow o) \rightarrow o$, but (semantically) their values in FOL are fixed in every model and (syntactically) you can't say things like $(\forall) = (\exists)$ that you can in higher-order logic. It's not a mistake in the SEP, but maybe a lack of clarity.

Comment: We both seem to agree that the claim "First-order logic considers only types of the form..." is wrong. PS. "FOL doesn't have types" doesn't hold water -- read the article.

Comment: FOL doesn't consider types at all. I think that the SEP article is saying something useful but maybe not properly qualified.  I don't think that MSE is a good forum for editorial feedback on the SEP in this case.